# Combining Video and Audio of different length in bulk

Tags: ffmpeg

I am going through a tv series right now and editing the files to be to my liking. I have one set which has the video I want and one set that has the audio. I have a batch file that I can run that takes the video from every file in folder "A" and the audio from every file in folder "B" and outputs it to a folder named "output." But with this particular series, that is only half of what I need done.

At the end of every episode of the files in the "B" folder there are some extra things. What I would like to do is take the audio and video from "A" and the audio from "B", combine it all into one file and also take the "A" and "B" files, compare the time stamps, and add the extra video from "B" to the output file.

Let me put it another way. Let's say "A" is 1080p with Japanese audio and is 20 minutes long. Let's say "B" is 720p with English audio and is 23 minutes long. I want the whole 1080p video with both audio tracks, plus the 720p video spliced onto the end. Both files start at the same spot so syncing isn't an issue. The issue is that the difference in time is different for every episode. So some episodes are 3 minutes longer, some only 30 seconds. Is there a way to make ffmpeg or another tool look at the difference in times and just add the excess to the output file?

Sorry for being long winded. Thanks for any help and guidance.

Comment: If you're ready to transcode, this can be done. If so, I'll post a command.

Comment: I have no problem transcoding. Both folders have videos in mkv format. Pretty sure they're all x264. I'm not at home right now to double check.

Comment: Mulvya, I was just wondering if you could post the command? With annotations would be awesome. Either way, I'm pretty alright with taking code and figuring out what it does. Thanks!

Comment: The 720 portion from B wlll have to be upscaled to 1080p, ok?

Comment: That's fine by me!

Comment: Not to be a pain Mulvya, but did you forget about me? Haha

Comment: Yes, I did. Give me a day or two.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both A and B start at the same time, so an initial sync pass is not required. And have the same framerate. A has the desired video 1080p and B has the audio + extras at the end.

```
ffmpeg -i A.mp4 -i B.mp4
  -filter_complex
      "[1][0]scale2ref[b][a];[b][a]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]"
  -map "[v]" -map 0:a -map 1:a -crf 18 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

`-i A.mp4 -i B.mp4` - first, we supply the two inputs to ffmpeg.

`-filter_complex` - if we wish to selectively apply filters to multiple inputs or process them in some interdependent manner, a filtergraph is setup, via `-filter_complex`. It's safest to enclose its whole argument in quotes.

`[1][0]scale2ref[b][a]` - the scale2ref filter scales the B video to be the same size as the A video, which is the reference. Then both those outputs are passed on to the overlay filter.

`[b][a]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]` - A is overlaid on top of the scaled up B. Since B now is the same size as A, A completely covers up the base video B. When A terminates, B shows through; the eof_action is added to enforce this - default behaviour would be for the last frame of A to get repeated till the end of B.   The output of this filter is labelled `[v]`.

`-map "[v]" -map 0:a -map 1:a` - ffmpeg has to be explicitly told which streams to include in the output, else it will automatically select them. Which isn't suitable in this case. The overlay result is included, as are both the audio tracks.

`-c:v libx264` - since we output to MP4, default encoder is libx264, It isn't specified here, but may be useful to know for future use.

`-crf 18` - the recommended encoding mode for libx264 is CRF. Smaller values preserve the source quality better but produce larger files. 18 to 28 is a good range to remain in.

`-c:a copy` - the mapped audio streams are copied over i.e. no recompression.

`-movflags +faststart` - after the processing is done, ffmpeg will move the index of the generated MP4 to its front, so that during web streaming, playback starts quickly. Can be skipped if file won't be streamed over a network.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try this later. I appreciate it!

Comment: Could you clarify what the map code does and what each command is for? I'm unfamiliar with pretty much all the code you used so the more details you'd be willing to give me the better.

Comment: You are absolutely amazing